# Program to show programs that are currently starting (in queue)

Tags: windows

A very old problem with Windows is that you sometimes start a program and you're not sure whether the program is starting or nothing will happen.
It would very useful if there was a program which shows that a program is starting up, so you know just to wait and not click again.

Does this exist?

Comment: Shouldn't the Task Manager that ships with the OS being capable of that? It should show all processes, including those not (yet) "visible" on the desktop.

Comment: Actually, in the particular case that made me ask this question it showed up for a second and disappeared. But I don't really want to search for every program I open in task manager, and have it open all the time, I was looking for something simpler and more visual.